Locally rotate bone in IK chain without affecting other bones
I have a long snakelike cylinder with 5 bones in it, attached to an IK control bone, to make it slither.

Now I want the IK target bone (the one that has the IK constraint modifier), to rotate locally (roll around it's y axis), without affecting other bones in the chain.
This is not working: The other bones slightly move, too.

How can I have one bone roll, without affecting other bones?
These are the constraint settings:

I am rotating with R + y in local transformation orientation.

In this gif you made doesn't seems like the other are also rotating. Can't you do this rig with Spline-IK rather?

@AAAYerus they're not rotating but they sure are moving.

Depending on the needs, it's better to do with Ik-spline, it's more precise.
